# PHP Validation form without using a regex

Tags: php

Im working with HTML form, then I send it to my php script, where I should check if a value from html form it's decimal. If not, php should print it using echo with red font-color and if it's correct with standard black font..

First of all, I CAN'T use regex, to check if it's formally valid.
Any clue?

Comment: if regex cannot be used, please remove the regex tag

Comment: How about PHP's is_numeric() function? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: What do you have until now? Please, add your code

Comment: I'll try use it for decimal. But also I've got other inputs: "validate if it's ternary numeral" and "c# object attribute reference"...

Comment: @mthrsj, I've got working script, which is getting a values from inputs.That's all. If I could use regex, I wouldn't ask for an idea :P

Comment: So add to your question, then we can help you

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways this could be achieved:

```
<?php
$values = [
    '1',
    '1.1',
    '.11',
    'foo'
];

foreach( $values as $value ){
    if( $value > floor($value) ){
        echo '<p>is decimal</p>';
    }else{
        echo '<p style="color:red">not decimal</p>';
    }
}

echo '<hr>';

foreach( $values as $value ){
    if( is_numeric($value) && (1 === substr_count($value, '.')) ){
        echo '<p>is decimal</p>';
    }else{
        echo '<p style="color:red">not decimal</p>';
    }
}
```

The first way just compares the value against a `floor()`-ed version of itself.

Alternatively, checks to see if the value `is_numeric()` then checks if the string has a decimal.

Edit: Changed the second method from `substr()` to `substr_count()` as @ArtisticPhoenix suggested as there may be the possibility of >= two decimals.

Comment: Maybe  `substr_count($value, '.') == 1` for the second one instead of `!(false === strpos($value,'.')` - I almost made an answer with it, then realized it was too similar to the second one.  In any case seems like `false !== strpos($value,'.')` would be more readable.